# How to find a condition for a strictly positive real function?

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n\in\mathbb{R}$ and define a complex function $f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$ as
$$
f(x) = \frac{k_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+k_2x+k_1}{x^n + k_nx^{n-1}+\cdots+k_2x+k_1}
$$
I am looking for a condition on which $\mathrm{Re}(f(x))>0$ for all $x$ on the imaginary axis, i.e., for all $x\in i\mathbb{R} = \{yi : y\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
Specifically, I want to find a condition of the coefficients $k_1,k_2,\dots,k_n$ that gives $\mathrm{Re}(f(x))>0$ for all $x\in i\mathbb{R}$.

My initial try was to factorize both the numerator and the denominator of $f(yi)$ as
$$
f(yi) = k_n\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(yi-z_j)}{\prod_{j=1}^n(yi-p_j)} = -i\frac{k_n}{y}\frac{\prod_{j=1}^{n-1}(1-z_j/(yi))}{\prod_{j=1}^n(1-p_j/(yi))} \quad (y\neq0)
$$
and then looking at the locations of solutions $z_j$ and $p_j$ that makes $\mathrm{Re}(f(yi))>0$ for all $y\in\mathbb{R}$.
However, I couldn't proceed further because the solutions $z_j$ and $p_j$ are coupled by the coefficients $k_j$.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what is the context of this?

Comment: @Conrad The complex function $f(x)$ is indeed a feedback transfer function of a SISO LTI system and coefficients $k_i$ are feedback gains. The property of strictly positive real of $f(x)$ is necessary for absolute stability.